# Invalid Spark URL in local spark session

Tags: apache-spark

since updating to Spark 2.3.0, tests which are run in my CI (Semaphore) fail due to a allegedly invalid spark url when creating the (local) spark context:

```
18/03/07 03:07:11 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Invalid Spark URL: spark://HeartbeatReceiver@LXC_trusty_1802-d57a40eb:44610
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointAddress$.apply(RpcEndpointAddress.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.asyncSetupEndpointRefByURI(NettyRpcEnv.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.util.RpcUtils$.makeDriverRef(RpcUtils.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:930)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:921)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
```

The spark session is created as following:

```
val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession
.builder
.appName(s"LocalTestSparkSession")
.config("spark.broadcast.compress", "false")
.config("spark.shuffle.compress", "false")
.config("spark.shuffle.spill.compress", "false")
.master("local[3]")
.getOrCreate
```

Before updating to Spark 2.3.0, no problems were encountered in version 2.2.1 and 2.1.0. Also, running the tests locally works fine.

Comment: How you run the application `sbt run` or `spark-submit`?

Comment: Neither, the code is executed within unit tests during the maven test phase.

Comment: I tried to run code by `sbt run` it was working fine, if its give you Invalid Spark URL: spark://HeartbeatReceiver@LXC_trusty_1802-d57a40eb:44610 then it not picking local as a master

Comment: Is your tests are running into the docker container?

Comment: The platform is an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS v1802 where it didn't work. One the local machine (Windows), it was no problem. However, thanks to your comment, I checked the platform settings in Semaphore, and switched to "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS v1802 (native Docker 17.12 support)".  I don't know why, but now I can execute again all tests without any problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same error since I upgraded to spark-core and spark-sql to 2.3.0
previous dependencies were org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.2.1 & org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.2.1 and current are org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.3.0 & org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.3.0

Comment: In what kind of environment does the error occur in your case?

Comment: *lsb_release -a* output:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty


*uname -a* output is:
Linux railsonfire_be98de61-c2bc-4afa-af27-3fe1058e603d_6cc13d6a6b9f 4.4.0-121-generic #145~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 16 18:40:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @LorenzBernauer - any ideas?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see your last reply.  In my case I switch the platform which runs my tests at my CI provider to Ubuntu with native Docker support. Somehow it solved the problem, but to be honest, I don't understand why.

Comment: @LorenzBernauer - it's weird because the `mvn clean install` command isn't within a docker

Comment: I actually also didn't use Docker... that is the part which I don't understand.

Answer (score 28):

Change the `SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME` to `localhost` and try.

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost
```

Comment: In windows platform you have to use

**SET SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost**

Answer (score 9):

This has been resolved by setting sparkSession config "spark.driver.host" to the IP address.

It seems that this change is required from 2.3 onwards.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to change the environment variable, you can change the code to add the config in the SparkSession builder (like Hanisha said above).

In PySpark:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.host", "localhost").getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Same syntax in scala.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in above answers, You need to change **SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME** to localhost. In windows, you have to use SET command, `SET SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost`

but this SET command is temporary. you may have to run it again and again in every new terminal. but instead, you can use SETX command, which is permanent.

```
SETX SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME localhost
```

You can type above command in any place. just open a command prompt and run above command. Notice that unlike SET command, SETX command do not allow equation mark. you need to separate environment variable and the value by a Space.

if Success, you will see a message like *"SUCCESS: Specified value was saved"*

you can also verify that your variable is successfully added by just typing `SET` in a different command prompt. (or type `SET s`  , which gives variables, starting with the letter 'S'). you can see that SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost in results, which will not happen if you use SET command instead of SETX

Comment: Thank you so so much, I was trying many tutorials until I found your answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your hostname to have NO underscore.

spark://HeartbeatReceiver@LXC_trusty_1802-d57a40eb:44610 to spark://HeartbeatReceiver@LXCtrusty1802d57a40eb:44610

Ubuntu AS root

```
#hostnamectl status
#hostnamectl --static set-hostname LXCtrusty1802d57a40eb

#nano /etc/hosts
    127.0.0.1   LXCtrusty1802d57a40eb
#reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone working in **Jupyter Notebook**. Adding `%env SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost` to the very beginning of the cell solved it for me. Like so:

```
%env SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost

import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Test")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `.config("spark.driver.host", "localhost")` fixed the issue for me.

```
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .config("spark.master", "local")
            .config("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.buffer.dir", "/tmp")
            .config("spark.driver.memory", "2048m")
            .config("spark.executor.memory", "2048m")
            .config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1")
            .config("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
            .getOrCreate();
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of an of existing answer., by @Felipe. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers. Remember to review all existing answers first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Spark locally, with as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine :

```
.master("local[*]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to complement @Prakash Annadurai answer by saying:

If you want to make the variable settlement last after exiting the terminal, add it to your shell profile (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`) with the same command:

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost
```