# Is there a config file when installing spark dependency with scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I installed spark with sbt in project dependecies. Then I want to change variables of the spark env without doing it within my code with a `.setMaster()`. The problem is that i cannot find any config file on my computer.

This is because I have an error : `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Invalid Spark URL: spark://HeartbeatReceiver@my-mbp.domain_not_set.invalid:50487`even after trying to change my hostname. Thus, I would like to go deep into spark library and try some things.

I tried pretty much everything that is on this so post : [Invalid Spark URL in local spark session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143271/invalid-spark-url-in-local-spark-session).

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for the issue:

`export SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost` in shell profil (e.g. `~/.bash_profil`)

SBT was not able to find the host even using the command just before running sbt. I had to put it in the profil to have a right context.