# Py4JJavaError: . : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Invalid Spark URL: spark://HeartbeatReceiver@kshitij_computer.mshome.net:50675

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Invalid Spark URL: spark://HeartbeatReceiver@kshitij_computer.mshome.net:50675
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointAddress$.apply(RpcEndpointAddress.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.asyncSetupEndpointRefByURI(NettyRpcEnv.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.util.RpcUtils$.makeDriverRef(RpcUtils.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:501)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried to change my local host name from kshitij_computer to kshitijcomputer

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

lines = sc.textFile("file:///SparkCourse/ml-100k/u.data")
ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split()[2])
result = ratings.countByValue()

sortedResults = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items()))
for key, value in sortedResults.items():
    print("%s %i" % (key, value))
```

Why is this error coming ?

Invalid Spark URL: spark://HeartbeatReceiver@kshitij_computer.mshome.net:50675

Answer (score 1):

The underscore in your hostname is probably the problem. One solution might be changing it or downgrading to Spark 2.2.2. You can also check these solitions: [Invalid Spark URL in local spark session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143271/invalid-spark-url-in-local-spark-session/51356375)